# string comparison and changing order of array

Tags: php, regex, arrays

Trying to create a search for users where I have an array like this:

**Original Array:**

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
      array(1) {
        ["string"]=>"One two three, Blue, Green, Yellow"
      }
  [2]=>
      array(1) {
        ["string"]=>"One two four, Blue, Green, Yellow"
      }
}
```

Now how can I do a regex with the words from input field which could be "one two blue four" and then change the given array order (in this case to):

```
array(2) {
   [1]=>
      array(1) {
        ["string"]=>"One two four, Blue, Green, Yellow"
      }
  [2]=>
      array(1) {
        ["string"]=>"One two three, Blue, Green, Yellow"
      }
}
```

Cause **Original Array [2]** has got more matches. Also I would like the order to change already if a user writes "one two blue f"

I've tried with array_diff but I need some opposite array_diff function (showing all the matches) and probably a regex to make it work with single letters.

Any advices would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would explode the search term and check each word with [`stripos()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) or [`substr_count()`](https://www.php.net/substr_count) against the string in the array. The one that has more occurrences goes up if it has less it goes down. You can use [`usort()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) for this.

Your sorter could look like this one:

```
class OccurrenceSorter {
    private $searchTerm;

    public function sort(array $arr, $searchTermStr) {
        $this->searchTerm = preg_split('/\s+/', $searchTermStr);
    
        usort($arr, array($this, 'doSort'));
        
        return $arr;
    }
    
    private function doSort($a, $b) {
        $aScore = $this->getScore($a['string']);
        $bScore = $this->getScore($b['string']);
        
        if($aScore == $bScore)
            return 0;
        
        return ($aScore < $bScore)?1:-1;
    }
    
    private function getScore($str) {
        $score = 0;
        $strLower = strtolower($str);
        
        foreach($this->searchTerm as $st) {
            // substr_count() or strpos() depending on the wished behavior 
            $score += substr_count($strLower, strtolower($st));
        }
        
        return $score;
    }
}

$arr = array(
    array('string' => 'One two three, Blue, Green, Yellow'),
    array('string' => 'One two four, Blue, Green, Yellow')
);

$searchTerm = 'one two blue four';

$rs = new OccurrenceSorter();
$sortedArr = $rs->sort($arr, $searchTerm);

var_dump($sortedArr);
```

Please note that I used `substr_count()` in the example abouth. So the string

```
two four, four, four, Blue, Blue, Green, Yellow
```

Is "higher" than the following string (altough this string covers more **different** search terms):

```
One two four, Blue, Green, Yellow
```

In total the first string has 6 matches (two, four, four, four, Blue, Blue) and the second one has 4 matches (One, two, four, Blue). If this is not the wished behavior use `strpos()`. You can then use `substr_count()` if `strpos()` of `a` and `b` are the same to get one higher ranked than the other.

Comment: this is almost to awesome ( I was on a verry wrong way), thank you soo much, trying to understand whats going on in this code, maybe some questions will follow